# Чудеса со строками в 1с

Tags: 1с

Проверено на 8.3.12.1595 и 8.3.13.1644

```
Сообщить(стрДлина("232"));  //выводит 3
Сообщить(стрДлина("2322"));  //выводит 4
// но, какие-то чудеса ниже, для трёх чисел длина 3, а для четырёх уже 5. 
А=232; 
Сообщить( стрДлина(строка(А)) );  //выводит 3
А=2322;
Сообщить( стрДлина(строка(А)) );  //выводит 5
```

Это баг или я дурак? Как это вообще понять?

Comment: Hу это-же 1С! =)))) у тебя там случайно не 2з22 ? Тогда русская буква "З" будет как раз 2 байта!

Comment: Используем ctrl+f чтоб искать тройки на странице и можно самостоятельно убедится что это не буква "зэ". Это число три.

Answer (score 7):

Если зайти в конструктор формата, там будет видно, что 1С ставит по умолчанию пробелы и получается не 1000, а 1 000. Надо смотреть функцию Формат.

```
ЧислоСтрокой=Формат( А,"ЧГ=0");
```